# PHP exec octave sh in Windows

Tags: php, octave

I'm trying to execute the following octave sh file in php  using the exec command running in Windows 2008. This command works in Unix but I don't know why it doesn't work in Windows. Seems that the working directory of Octave is C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile 
Please advice.

```
exec("octave ./d_test.sh");
```

Comment: Try: `exec("octave ./d_test.sh 2>&1", $output); echo implode("\n", $output);` What do you get?

Comment: The octave path is C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile How to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved :) I edited the octaverc in 'c:\software\Octave\Octave3.6.2_gcc4.6.2\share\octave\site\m\startup' with

```
addpath("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Apache Software Foundation\\Apache2.2\\htdocs\\test");
addpath("C:\\Windows\\system32\\config\\systemprofile")
##cd(getenv('USERPROFILE'))
```

Answer (score -1):

You're better off just figuring out where octave is and calling it using that absolute path, ex. `exec("C:\Octave-3.6.1\bin\octave.exe ./d_test.sh");`.